# Magento 2 Admin Notifications - what makes a notification popup when the admin user logs in?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, messages, user, notification

Occasionally, an admin notification can pop up when an admin user logs into the Admin Panel.

The popup usually shows in an orange style box and can be closed easily, but not all poups show like this.

I would imagine that certain message severity (\Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface) would decided this, but it appears not.

Does anybody know what logic is in place to decide whether an admin notification is displayed as a popup, rather than just sitting in the notifications area and never being presented to the user?

Comment: Usually the only messages which are displayed are the system messages there are messages which magento sees as being a priority message and typically are shown when they have not been marked as read or the action in which they relate to has not been met. as for the priorities there are 4 types which are Critical, Major,Minor, Notice. setting up these types of actions is a pretty simple process